Vue2 doesn't see updates of object in expanded table vuetify
I have a problem with reactivity in Vue2
I have an array of objects in Vuex, which are displayed in v-data-table, inside each object I have an array that is filled with data when row expanded, I want to see this array in the expanded property, but when calling a method that fills this data array, the changes are not displayed in expanded lines, but I can see changes in devtools.
The first time I open expanded row, changes don't displayed, but if I close the row and open it again the changes are displayed.
This is my default object in array
{
  "OfferId": 101581,
  "VaweStart": "2024-03-28",
  "VaweEnd": "2024-04-10",
  "OfferDetails": []
}

This is my updated object in array
{
  "OfferId": 101581,
  "VaweStart": "2024-03-28",
  "VaweEnd": "2024-04-10",
  "OfferDetails": [
    [
      {
        "OfferId": 101581,
        "PositionName": "Test",
        "PositionCode": "449455"
      },
      {
        "OfferId": 101581,
        "PositionName": "Test",
        "PositionCode": "701133"
      }
    ],
    [
      {
        "OfferId": 101581,
        "PositionName": "Test",
        "PositionCode": "449455"
      },
      {
        "OfferId": 101581,
        "PositionName": "Test",
        "PositionCode": "701133"
      }
    ]
  ]
}


This is my v-data-table
        <v-data-table
          :headers="headers"
          :items="getPersonalOffersInfo"
          :expanded.sync="expanded"
          item-key="OfferId"
          show-expand
          class="elevation-1"
          @click:row="clickRow"
        >
          <template v-slot:expanded-item="{ headers, item }">
            <td :colspan="headers.length">
              <v-data-table 
                :items="item.OfferDetails[0]" 
                :headers="subheaders"
                hide-default-footer
                >
                <template v-slot:item="{ item }">
                  <tr>
                    <td>{{ item }}</td>
                    <td>{{ item.PositionName }}</td>
                    <td>{{ item.PositionCode }}</td>
                    
                  </tr>
                </template>
              </v-data-table>
            </td>
          </template>
        </v-data-table>

By click i callback method with push data into OfferDetails array
This is my set property in vuex for this array
setPersonalOffersDetailSQL(state, results) {
    const offerId = results[0].OfferId
    const objectToFind = state.PersonalOffersInfo.findIndex(
      (i) => i.OfferId === offerId
    )

    state.PersonalOffersInfo[objectToFind].OfferDetails.splice(0, 0, [...results])
},

I have tried to change use MapGetters, but it didnt help
...mapGetters('discountcard', ['getPersonalOffersInfo'])


In Vue2, when using "array subscript to modify values" or "when adding object key values", the devsrve function of Vue cannot listen for changes in data, which leads to data updates, but the view cannot trigger updates because data updates are not monitored.
state.PersonalOffersInfo[objectToFind].OfferDetails.splice(0, 0, [...results])

change to
let personalOffersInfo = state.PersonalOffersInfo[objectToFind]
personalOffersInfo.OfferDetails.splice(0, 0, [...results])
state.PersonalOffersInfo.splice(objectToFind,1,personalOffersInfo)

